# Calling private sub from module, concatenated reference

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a couple of forms (i.e. frmTest) with bound comboboxes (i.e. cboTest). I'm trying to solve the NotInList event by a public sub, which calls back a button click sub's in these forms (i.e. btnTest_Click).

Form frmTest:

```
Private Sub cboTest_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
     Response = acDataErrContinue
     Item_NotInList NewData, Me, "btnTest"
End Sub

Public Sub btnTest_Click
    '....
End sub
```

Module:

```
Public strNotInList_Text As String
'public variable to store entered text

Public Sub Item_NotInList (strNewData As string, frmForm As Form, strControl As String)
     Dim strControl_Sub As String
     strNotInList_Text = strNewData
     strControl_Sub = "." & strControl & "_Click"
     Application.Run frmForm.Name & strControl_Sub
End Sub
```

Acces returns an error "Program ... didn't found a procedure frmTest.btnTest_Click."

Why ?

Reference frmTest.btnTest_Click looks to be correct. Sub btnTest_Click is declared as public.

Thank you for yor help.

Comment: It would be better to just not store `btnTest_Click` inside the form, store it in your module (`btnTestClick`) and call it from the test button using `Sub btnTest_Click() \\ btnTestClick  \\ End Sub`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But btn..._Click subs in various forms are handling various procedures; that's why I'm using btn..._Click subs in forms.

Comment: Run simply can't do that. You could use a public object variable that you store the form in, then call its method directly, or make the routine Public and use `CallByName` to call it. I can't say I see any benefit to this setup though.

Comment: Thank you, Rory. Can you help me with a little more detailed explanation of `CallByName` function ? My `btnTest_Click` procedure is declared as public, thats why I tried in my module:

`Public Sub Item_NotInList (strNewData As string, frmForm As Form,     strControl As String)
         ...
         CallByName frmForm, strControl_Sub, VbLet
End Sub`

But no success ...

Comment: @Duski Of course they're handling various procedures, you can still use this setup and name the subs uniquely... Having almost all your code in modules instead of forms greatly helps later maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you create an interface let say `IMyInterface` with this method `btnTest_Click` (should be named differently) and let the forms you want to call this method implement this interface. Then change the signature of `Item_NotInList` like this:

```
Public Sub Item_NotInList (strNewData As string, frmForm As IMyInterface, strControl As String)
' ...
frmForm.btnTest_Click 
' ...
```

Because the instance of the form is available in the method `Item_NotInList` you simply call the target method. Does this help?

---

Example:

Add class module and name it e.g. `IMyInterface` (can be named according to your needs). Add empty body of the method (don't add any implementation).

> IMyInterface

```
Public Sub TestClick()
    ' will be implemented in your forms
End Sub
```

Then implement this interface in your forms e.g. in Form frmTest and others which should be used with the `Item_NotInList` method.

> Form frmTest example

```
Implements IMyInterface

Private Sub IMyInterface_TestClick()
    ' here  goes your implementation
End Sub
```

> Standard Module test code

```
Sub test()
    Dim f1 As UserForm1
    Set f1 = New UserForm1

    Item_NotInList f1

    Dim f2 As UserForm2
    Set f2 = New UserForm2

    Item_NotInList f2
End Sub

Sub Item_NotInList(testForm As IMyInterface)
    testForm.TestClick
End Sub
```

Thats it. HTH

Comment: Thank you for your response, dee, but I'm afraid, your solution is too complicated for me. I don't understand, what you mean under interface. I'm not very advanced in VBA.